# Clarifications needed about buck converter output ripple voltage derivation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck, switching-regulator

I have a question regarding buck converter output ripple. In the below figure, could you please tell me how the area shown in the red circle has a time duration of Ts/2?

[image]

Comment: It's the basic geometry of a buck converter's waveforms in CCM. There is no option other than to be what it is.

Comment: Hari, this is most basic geometry. you can assume the areas to be triangles and the lines to be straight if the inductor is sufficiently large for the chosen switching frequency. In steady state, the area above and below the horizontal line are also equal ( i.e. mean current is constant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The waveform is symmetrical.

It's not asserting that the on time and off time are equal, D'Ts and DTs are still unequal.

The time between the indicated points is half the on time + half the off time. So the remaining time is half the off time + half the on time. Equal. Each equal to half the total cycle time.

Comment: If the on time and off time are not equal how can we take half the off time + half the on time.Is it due to symmetry of the waveform.

Answer (score 1):

The t axis is drawn at the average inductor current - that's how much the load takes if we assume the regulator does its job.

The rising part of inductor current occurs when the switch is ON. The falling part of inductor current occurs when the switch is OFF.

That can look obscure, but it's the about 200 years old induction law by Faraday and Henry: The current of the inductor changes with rate U/L where U is the voltage between the ends of the inductor (assuming there's no resistance) and L is inductance. U/L gives unit amperes per second when U is volts and L is henries.

The capacitor voltage grows as long as the inductor current is higher than what the load takes.

Rise and fall are assumed for simplicity to be linear -  that's common in elementary analysis texts and it's applicable if we assume the voltage ripple is small, say 1% of the nominal output voltage and the input voltage  stays constant during the switch ON state.

In linear change the average is at the half height of the ramp.

The half height of a linear ramp occurs at the half duration of the ramp.